# Error with shortcuts static to show in the launcher

Tags: android, android-static-shortcuts

I was following the official documentation for making shortcuts to show in the launcher. When I start testing I get this error. How can I fix it? what am I doing wrong?

```
Error:(6, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/compose_icon').
Error:(8, 36) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'shortcutLongLabel' with value '@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1').
```

my code is this

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="compose"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/compose_icon"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_short_label1"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/compose_shortcut_long_label1"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/compose_disabled_message1">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
        android:targetClass="com.example.myapplication.ComposeActivity" />
    <!-- If your shortcut is associated with multiple intents, include them
         here. The last intent in the list determines what the user sees when
         they launch this shortcut. -->
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
<!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
```

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to provide a valid icon and string resource. Seems like you are trying out the sample in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#static) directly. The compiler will not point out errors in this file, so you need to be careful with the resources you mention.

Specifically, define `compose_shortcut_short_label1`, `compose_shortcut_long_label1` and `compose_disabled_message1` in your strings with proper names and also a valid drawable resource for `compose_icon`.

Also change the `android:targetPackage` and `android:targetClass` attributes accordingly.